# Is the safe area in iOS strictly enforced by the operating system?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm rather new to iOS programming. But I am wondering what will happen if I intentionally create view layout constraints that violate the safe area layout guidelines. Will the iOS operating system still respect them?

Will iOS simply quietly shift all my offending constraints from `view.topAnchor` to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`? Or maybe, even worse, my constraints will simply be ignored altogether?

Comment: It will reflect your constraints. Period. But have you tested things on different devices to see what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are guidelines for you to follow for your app to be a good iOS citizen. These are not enforced at run time.

It's your choice to use the guidelines that best fit your app's content. For example -

1. `UIImageView` instances, specially when used as backgrounds, are usually expected to cover the screen end-to-end extending under the safeArea like statusBar etc.
2. Main app content like titles, lists etc. are expected to stay clear of safeArea to be readable/scannable easily.

Will iOS simply quietly shift all my offending constraints from `view.topAnchor` to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`?

> iOS will respect what you asked, it will not automatically shift anchors quietly.

Or maybe, even worse, my constraints will simply be ignored altogether?

> No, it won't.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just to clarify, so iOS will basically always respect my constraints no matter what, right? Even if it makes the app look horrible or makes certain views overlap/go off-screen, iOS will always abide by the rules I set, correct?

Comment: Yes, it will respect what you set in code.